# Telerik filtering of DateTime values is incorrect

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

- Telerik 2015.1.401.45

I have the following column declared in my WebForms application:

```
<telerik:GridDateTimeColumn CurrentFilterFunction="GreaterThanOrEqualTo" DataField="ClockedInAt" DataType="System.DateTime" EditDataFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm" FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" FilterDateFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm" PickerType="DateTimePicker" UniqueName="column">
</telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
```

However when I apply the filter as per the image below:

[image]

I still appear to get records with times PRIOR to my filter term. Has anyone got any insight here as to why this is happening?

Comment: I can't tell clearly from your image. What's the time in the filter box?